# Efficient rolling Empirical Lower Tail Dependence Coefficient calculation in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to calculate a rolling Empirical Lower Tail Dependence Coefficient in data.table, here is the tail dependence coefficient function and a zoo::rollapply,
but this is awfully slow. For my data which has 1M rows it takes more than 6 hours. Is there a way to do it more efficiently?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
mydt = as.data.table(data.frame(id    = rep(LETTERS[1:4],each=10),
                                Time  = rep(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2017-10-01"),"day"),4),
                                x     = round(rnorm(40),2),
                                y     = round(rnorm(40),2)))

Tdc <- function(x, lower = TRUE, k = NULL){
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  k <- ifelse(is.null(k), floor(sqrt(nrow(x))),  as.integer(k))
  m <- nrow(x)
  N <- ncol(x)
  idx <- combn(N, 2)
  r <- apply(x, 2, data.table::frank)
  if(lower){
    td <- apply(idx, 2, function(y)
      sum((r[, y[1]] <= k) & (r[, y[2]] <= k)) / k)
  } else {
    td <- apply(idx, 2, function(y)
      sum((r[, y[1]] > m - k) & (r[, y[2]] > m - k)) / k)
  }
  return(td)
}

ltdc <- function(y)Tdc(as.data.frame(y[, c("x","y")]))
mydt[,LTDC := zoo::rollapplyr(.SD, 5, ltdc, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA), by = id]
```

I appreciate your ideas and comment on my code and/or my idea. Thank you.